# Ubuntu 13.04 icons look weird, please help

Tags: 13.04, icons, icon-themes

This is my Ubuntu's icons on Ambiance theme.
[image]

Most system icons are gone, the folder icon look like unknown file type icon.

But when I tried to switch to Radiance theme, icons look ok.
[image]

These are some screenshots that someone who has tried to help has asked me.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Please advice me what should I do???
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Unity-tweak-tool by -

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

open it , you will see that the selected icon pack is `locolor` , locolor is like that by default there is nothing missing as shown below-

[image: locolor]

now choose icon pack `Ubuntu-mono light` as shown below -

[image: Ubuntu-mono-light]

It will be fine now.

Comment: Ubuntu-mono-light solved my problem, what about if I liked to use Ubuntu-mono-dark instead is there way to get the icons not disappeared?

Comment: both of them are almost same .. try any . it wont change the icons, only coloro of lines in top panel will be diffrent..well if it solves your problem , accept it as answer for future reference for others,..

Comment: I still wonder because when I chose Ubuntu-mono-dark (which is my most prefer choice) the icons become disappeared again. Any ways to fix it???